# Closure of Open Balls Vs Corresponding Closed Balls in Normed Linear Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ be an $\mathbb{F}$ normed vector space and, for any $x \in V$ and $r>0$, let $$T=\{y \in V:\|y-x\| \leq r\}$$ and $$S=\{y \in V:\|y-x\|<r\}.$$

(a) Show that $T$ is closed and $S$ is open.

(b) If $z \in T$ and $z_n=\left(r-\frac{1}{n}\right) z$, for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, show that $\lim _{n \rightarrow \infty} z_n=z$ and hence show that $\bar{S}=T$

One can easily show $T$ is closed by showing $T^C=V-T$ is open using the basic open balls. However, I feel that we have to show that $z_n=(r-\frac{1}{n})z \in S$ whenever $z \in T$ prior to $\lim_{n \to \infty} z_n=z$.

That is, we need $\lVert (r-\frac{1}{n})z-x \rVert<r$, whenever $\lVert z-x \lVert=r,$ for each $n \in \Bbb N$. I am looking for a thread.

Comment: In (b) you should take $z_n= x+ (1-{1\over n})(z-x).$

Comment: @Ryszard Szwarc I think the convergence of $z_n=(r-1/n)z$ is not relevant here, right?

Comment: It seems wrong, as $z_n\to rz$.and you need $z_n\to z$ and $z_n\in S.$

Answer (score 1):

For any $z\in T$ we need to see $z_n=x+(1-1/n)(z-x)\in S$ for every $n\ge 1$. But this can be done easily:
$$
\Vert x+(1-1/n)(z-x)-x\Vert = \Vert (1-1/n)(z-x)\Vert = (1-1/n)r <r 
$$
as $\Vert z-x\Vert =r$.
Now clearly as $n\to \infty$ we have $z_n \to x+(z-x) = z$, so $z\in \overline{S}$. Thus, $T\subset \overline{S}$. As you have noted $T$ is closed. Clearly, $T$ contains $S$, so $T\supset \overline{S}$ by which we obtain $T=\overline{S}$.